# "What are you going to get him?" and " What are you going to give him?"

Tags: word-meaning

Is it correct to say that *What are you going to get him?* means *What are you going to give him?*

Can *get* be used to mean *give*?

> What are you going to get him?

Comment: In this context, 'yes!' But beware, they are ***not interchangeable*** all the time. Compare: You wanna see Niagara? Okay, I'll **get** you there, NOT **give you!**

Comment: @MaulikV nice, can you pick me up around 3?

Comment: @Kiamlaluno, thank you for editing. And thank you gays for answering.

Answer (score 2):

The "get" implies

> What are you going to get him **from the shops**?

which means the same as

> What are you going to give him?

So "get" does not mean "give", although the sentences mean the same. It is not giving, but obtaining the present, so when someone says

> I have got him a hat.

It means they have bought a present but not yet given it.

Comment: It may also be an ellipsis of prepositions: What are you going to get **for** him, and What are you going to give **to** him.